Проблема с кодировкой в ffmpeg
Пытаюсь вылавливать ошибки при преобразовании файла в ffmpeg. Но возникают проблемы с кодировкой в коде:
try:
    cmd = "ffmpeg -i /test.mp4 -c:v libaom-av1 -pix_fmt yuv420p /output.mkv"
    process = sub.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.STDOUT, text=True, encoding='latin-1')
while True:
    gg  = process.stdout.readline().rstrip('\n')
    print(gg) #Выводим в консоль 
    #Проверяем, если процесс завершился, тормозим цикл
    retcode = process.poll()
    if retcode is not None:
        break

    # Получаем код возврата
    retcode = process.wait()  # ждем завершения процесса
    if retcode != 0:
        raise sub.CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)

except sub.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(f"Ошибка выполнения команды: {e.cmd}")
    print(f"Код возврата: {e.returncode}")
    
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Произошла ошибка: {str(e)}")


Произошла ошибка: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position
3973: invalid continuation byte

Ок, ставлю encoding='latin-1'. Ошибки нет, но теперь в консоли русские буквы выглядят как иероглифы.
Ряд вопросов:

Как поправить кодировку, метаданные видео в ероглифах в консоли Ñ�Ð°Ñ�
Перестает выводить в консоль перед началом преобразования... Как только метаданные отобразит в консоли. Как продолжить отображать в консоль построчно до кончания


попробуйте кодировку "ansi"

Пожалуйста, скорректируйте вопрос. У вас в вопросе содержится несколько тем, представляющих собой отдельные вопросы. "Как задать хороший вопрос": https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

ansi, не помогает, нет формата такого пишет... Вопрос поправил

windows-1254,  'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 517: character maps to <undefined>

Мне прогресс бар пока не в приоритете.  Пытаюсь собрать все строчки в качестве логов, а также вывести их в консоль в процессе. Если возникает ошибка, записать в файл в дальнейшем... Вот и все...

На win 10 ansi помогает, правда сам код в итоге зависает на бесконечном чтении stdout. Впрочем, если вообще убрать кодировки, то все равно виснет на этом после 3-х выводов прогресса

В консоли русскоязычной windows по умолчанию кодировка cp866
